# c++ with SDL not running

Tags: c++, sdl, mingw32

i've installed SDL to develop a program, and while on the test phase for this lib, the compiled code does not execute, and i mean it won't even open the cmd box. The weird thing is, it occasionally executes.
I'm using Eclipse Hellios with minGW32 and i686-w64-mingw32 on windows10.
My test code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int, char**)
{

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0) return 1;
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("", 300, 100, 1024, 800, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "SDL init Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

    SDL_Surface *background = SDL_LoadBMP("Resources/Lilothyn.bmp");
    if (background == NULL)
    {
        SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox(0, "Background init error", SDL_GetError(), window);
        return 1;
    }

    if (renderer == NULL)
    {
        SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox(0, "Renderer init error", SDL_GetError(), window);
    }
    SDL_Texture *texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, background);
    if (texture == NULL)
    {
        SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox(0, "Texture init error", SDL_GetError(), window);
    }

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    SDL_Event event;
    bool running = true;

    while(running)
    {
        SDL_PollEvent(&event);
        switch(event.type)
        {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            running = false;
            SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
            SDL_FreeSurface(background);
            SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
            SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
            SDL_Quit();
            break;
        default: break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the odd thing is, i previously had "SDL_LoadBMP("Resources/TommyBMP.bmp");" and it executed properly. Changing a string shouldn't make the program stop working, both files are at the Debug/Resources folder so it can't be a case of not finding them...

note: further testing shows that a simple "hello world" has the same issue, so the problem will likely not be from SDL.

"help me obi wan, you're my only hope".

Comment: So what does your debugger say, is there something unusual when you step through your program?

Comment: Just tried you code on my msys2 setup and not a single time it crashes (I created my own bmp file, as you didn't post one). Tried check the run configuration, may be you have multiple one and the runing directory is different.

Comment: i've been avoiding running in eclipse, as it gets stuck, I've just tried again to run in debug mode, and it gets stuck on launching progress 97%. The program never gets to start, so there is no output

Comment: @wutipong: what do you mean different running directories? the output .exe is always generated on the same location. i did check it.

Comment: Well even though the output is created in the Debug directory(for example) , it does not always mean it will be run from there. A working directory can be set in the launcher, and it would acted like the file is in the directory and run from there..... Anyway if you're sure the code is right then try running the app from the Debug directory directly (by double click it or whatever). If there are complaints about missing dll, just copy them from the mingw dir to the Debug and retry again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I have all the DLLs in the folder, what I'm doing is passing all those files to a different computer and it runs there. I think it may be something to do with my computer's settings for either C++ or Windows itself.